# Update an outdated branch against master in a Git repo

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a Git repository that has branch (local and remote) that has become outdated. I would like to bring this branch up to date with the master branch, but I don't know how to do this. There will also probably be many merge conflicts.

How can I bring or update this out-of-date branch to the same state as the master branch?

Comment: if you have come here to find out how to update an outdated branch against master in a Git repo if you havent made any changes in the local branch then simply do a "git pull"

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Update the master branch, which you need to do regardless.

Then, one of:

1. Rebase the old branch against the master branch.  Solve the merge conflicts during rebase, and the result will be an up-to-date branch that merges cleanly against master.
2. Merge your branch into master, and resolve the merge conflicts.
3. Merge master into your branch, and resolve the merge conflicts.  Then, merging from your branch into master should be clean.

None of these is better than the other, they just have different trade-off patterns.

I would use the rebase approach, which gives cleaner overall results to later readers, in my opinion, but that is nothing aside from personal taste.

To rebase and keep the branch you would:

```
git checkout <branch> && git rebase <target>
```

In your case, check out the old branch, then

```
git rebase master
```

to get it rebuilt against master.

Comment: `git checkout $branch && git rebase $target` - in your case, check out the old branch, then `git rebase master` to get it rebuilt against master.

Comment: Is your repo public?  Is it okay to rebase if it's public?

Comment: Good advice when using rebase in remote branches: do this remote branch rebase against master branch only when anyone is not pushing commits on this remote branch.

Comment: Once rebase is done, you need to push the changes using `-f` option. As you are rewriting the history, forceful push is required.

Comment: Yeh rebasing can be really annoying if you have to do that for every branch. You can also disable the setting from Github that "requires the branch to be up to date before merging" and then you can merge without updating the branch. There are also some tools that can do that automatically for you. One I've used in past is called https://mergequeue.com/. This tool can automatically rebase the branches before merging.